# Change date format for different variants of SQL

Tags: string-manipulation

Wrote this code to change MS Access variant of SQL date format to T-SQL, basically recognize dates delimited with pounds and change pounds to single quotes

My Mathematica code is Pythonic, because I use a `Do` loop

How would you do it?

```
changeDateFormat01[s_String] := Block[
  {ss, pp},
  ss = s;
  Do[
    ss = StringReplacePart[ss, 
      "'" <> StringTake[ss, {pp[[1]] + 1, pp[[2]] - 1}] <> "'", pp],
   {pp, Reverse@
     StringPosition[ss, RegularExpression["\\#\\d+\\/\\d+\\/\\d+\\#"]]}
   ];
  ss
 ]

changeDateFormat01["hello#1/1/2013#hello#donotbefooled#1/1/2013hello#1/1/2013#hello"]

(* "hello'1/1/2013'hello#donotbefooled#1/1/2013hello'1/1/2013'hello" *)
```

Comment: We don't use SMS style in this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

```
str1 = "hello#1/1/2013#hello#donotbefooled#1/1/2013hello#1/1/2013#hello";
```

then

```
StringReplace[str1, 
 "#" ~~ dt : (DigitCharacter.. ~~ "/" ~~ DigitCharacter.. ~~ "/" ~~ 
      DigitCharacter..) ~~ "#" :> "'" ~~ dt ~~ "'"]
```

produces

```
"hello'1/1/2013'hello#donotbefooled#1/1/2013hello'1/1/2013'hello"
```

without a loop in sight.  Note that I've used *Mathematica's* own string expression syntax, but you could just as easily use regular expressions if you prefer.

I'll leave it to you to wrap the foregoing snippet into a function, that seems to be well within your grasp.